# Cant handle event in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I was trying to handle an event in vue.js , But i think the function mm is out of scope . the error i am getting is [Vue warn]: v-on:mouseover="mm" expects a function value, got undefined .

This is my code

```
    var menuHover=new Vue({
            e1:'#t',
            data:{
                active:true
            },
            methods: {
                mm: function()
                {
                    alert(1);
                    This.active=!this.active;
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

This is my html

```
        <div id="t" v-on:mouseover="mm">
            <ul v-show="active">
                 <li>Test vue</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I tried several links and solutions , none of them worked .

Comment: appart from a few typos in your code ( `e1:` instead of `el:`, `This` instead of `this`), it works as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/xo0pwgjd/

Answer (score 0):

try this:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbpmrck/rLq7hofs/4/),i have run this and success.

```
   <div id="app" v-on:mouseover="mm">
       {{message}}
        <ul v-show="active">
             <li>Test vue</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is the js:

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   data: {
   active:true,
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   },
    methods: {
            mm: function(){
                alert(1);
                this.active=!this.active;
            }
        }
 })
```

Comment: The brackets are not nessessary, so that's not a solution.